# Javascript object property appears as undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the following code, why is `user.latitude` undefined?

```
console.log(user);
console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
console.log(user.latitude);
```

[image]

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify(user)` is giving you empty object. Are you reassigning user object somewhere.

Comment: @VinodBhavnani He's not stringifying it, `stringify` does not work in place, it returns a new string.

Comment: Ohh cool. My bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you print an `object` to `console`, it will not print the data inside `object` right away. When you expand that `object` in `console` at that time it is evaluated. Most probably at the time of printing to console your object is empty, but when you expand it, it is filled with co-ordinates just before that.

Comment: This seems especially true since the object has lat/lng properties, suggesting an async request to some kind of Map API.